# Tree that sorts classes hierarchicly

Tags: java, class, data-structures, tree, hierarchy

I need a tree-structure that sorts all added classes hierarchically. I have to get all classes that inherit one certain class. That one particular read access needs to be very fast.

Example:

I add the following classes.

```
public static class Event
{

}

public static class PlayerEvent extends Event
{

}

public static class PlayerMoveEvent extends PlayerEvent
{

}

public static class WorldEvent extends Event
{

}
```

It should sort the classes like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqehS.png

Comment: only sub-class have a information about its super class. reverse is not possible.

Comment: It seems you would need to scrape the Java API and the code files in your directories to find this information.

Comment: You didn't understand my question. I have a list of all sorts of classes and i need to get all that inherit one particular class. I think that a tree would be perfect for this problem.

Comment: Can you give an example of how this tree should behave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a Node class that represents a node in your tree.
It stores the class that it represents and its direct children.

```
class Node {
    Set<Node> children;
    Class class;
}
```

Then you can construct the tree, and get your root node.

```
List<Class> classList = ...l
Map<Class,Node> classMap = ... a map from all your classes to nodes made from them;
Node rootNode = null;

for(Class c : classList){
    Node parentNode = classMap.get(c.getSuperclass());
    if(parentNode != null)
        parentNode.children.add(classMap.get(c));
    else
        rootNode = classMap.get(c);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is what i need, but i think its too slow to check every class every time.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Map <Class, List <Class>>`, where the key is the parent class, and the List contains all the children.

Comment: That seems very memory-intensive. And is likely to be very slow at adding classes.

Answer (score 0):

Andres answer is best for O(1) lookup.
You always have to iterate if you are using a hierarchial data structure . If you want to store the hierarchial data structure so that you can have O(1) retrieval , you need to have memory to snapshot it. Java stores references , so it wont be as much memory as you are thinking of, but it still would not be insignificant. If you want to save on memory you can use disk sapce by writing  the values of the child classes to a file . Every time you add a child class, you append a row to the list of child classes.